# Что быстрее regex или стандартный str.replace()

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Встал вопрос выбора между регулярками и стандартным методом str.replace...
Что быстрее ? Как с нагрузкой на компьютер ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Статья по анализу скорости работы различных методов замены подстроки в Python](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/python/137089/)

Comment: Спасибо , что то не обратил внимания во время гугления

Comment: Просто у неё название не очевидное. Я еслиб сам не прочитал её - тоже бы не догадался...